# Binary `neighbors` perfect polynomials, instead of `consecutive`

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Inspired by Andrei's nice solution of 52609, (namely `consecutive` perfect polynomials):
Denote by $A$ the full ring of polynomials in one variable $t$ over the finite field with $2$ elements.
For any polynomial $P \in A$ define
$$
\sigma(P) =  \sum_{d \mid A} d.
$$
A polynomial $P \in A$ is called `perfect` if
$$
P = \sigma(P).
$$
If $P$ has no roots in $GF(2)$ then $P$ is `odd`, otherwise it is `even`.

Andrei proved:

$P$ is odd perfect iff $P$ is perfect and $P$ is a square in $A,$ and deduced:

$P$ and $P+1$ cannot both be perfect.

Observe that one of $P,P+1$ is odd while the other is even.

Take now a  polynomial $P \in A.$ What is the `next` polynomial of the same `type`?
i.e., having the same `parity`. Seems that the following definition is appropriate for this:

Call `neighbors`  two polynomials $P,Q \in A$  if $\deg(P)>2$ and ($Q=P+t(t+1)$ or $P=Q+t(t+1)$).

Question: There are neighbors polynomials $P,Q \in A$ such that $P$ and $Q$ are both perfect ?

Comment: Google says: voisins --> neighbors, not neighbords. So, I corrected
the post accordingly. Is perhaps a too literal translation.

Comment: It is not the same thing but (seems to me) that there is a conjecture Gary Mullen ?)
claiming infinity of irreducible polynomials $Q$ and $Q+t^2+t$
over a finite field with an even cardinal.